# Arithmetic Pointers referencing same addresses

Tags: c, pointers, assignment-operator, order-of-execution

I'm struggling a bit to understand the following operation :

B is variable, Pt1 and Pt2 are pointing to &B

[image]

The decrement is done after the affectation, so with my logic it should be 68 but my IDE gives me 69, can someone explain ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have given creates undefined behaviour! Taking away the pointer aspect, you are essentially doing this:

```
B = B--;
```

This cannot be consistently resolved, because you are assigning `B` the value of `69` and ***then*** post-decrementing `B`. So, which gives the answer: the assignment or the post-decrement?

With your platform/IDE, the compiler has done something like this, using a 'temporary' variable:

```
// Initial value of B is 69
temp = B--; // temp is 69 and B is now 68
B = temp;   // B now has the value of 69!
```

However, you cannot rely on this 'interpretation' - either across different compilers, or even using similar code at different places with the same compiler!

PS: Incidentally, you should post code as text, formatted as a code-block.

Comment: "So, which gives the answer: the assignment or the post-decrement?" Whichever is evaluated first. There is no way to reason logically about this, because there is no reason why the order of evaluation wouldn't be deterministic, as shown in C++17. However, the C committee insists that the C language must remain broken and so the order is unspecified. You need to point at the standard in order to answer this, you can't write an answer based on logic reasoning, because the language isn't rational.

Comment: That being said, code such as `B = B--` is of course not rational either.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard 6.5 gives this cryptic explanation to this phenomenon:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar
>   object, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the
>   subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side
>   effect occurs in any of the orderings.

- "Scalar object" in this case means your original variable pointed-at.
- "Value computation" in this case is de-referencing either of the pointers. They point to the same variable.
- "Side-effect" in this case means modifying a variable. Both the `=` assignment and the `--` operator are side effects.

The assignment operator does not specify an order of evaluation of its operands (6.5.16 "The evaluations of the operands are unsequenced."). It isn't specified if `*Pt2` happens before or after `*Pt1--`.

This means that the compiler is placed in a situation where it must update the same variable twice, at once. Since this isn't a well-defined scenario, the compiler might produce incorrect code. Code that can display strange values or even crash. This is known as *undefined behavior* - a bug that puts your program in a state where you can no longer rely on deterministic behavior or predict any result.

The simple way to avoid this is to follow this best practice rule:

***Never use the ++ or -- operators together with other operators in the same expression.***